# Proftpd Anonymous login?

Tags: debian, proftpd

I'm trying to set my virtual host on anonymous login but it doesn't work as everytime I log in, it keeps asking me for username and password, please check the screen shot below :

[image]

Any idea what might be the issue ?

Comment: What are you entering when it asks for user and password? What error do you get?

Comment: I'm entrting my user name as stated above "ftp1" and i'm inside my server, so no error msg, but i would like to open my ftp site address and it should ask me for no login, to make it "Anonumous" as I made it at the configuration file above.

Comment: I  even can't get in with taping "anonymous" as login, and admin@domain.com as password, did I miss something with the configuration of virtuals.conf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by adding the fbelow to the anonymous tag :

user ftp1
usergroup ftp1
UserAlias anonymous ftp1

Now, it doesnt ask me for the login anymore and I can access my ftp server just by putting its adress on the navigator search bar.

Cheers,